# Have SELinux allow syslog and logrotate to handle files outside of /var/log

Tags: centos, selinux, rsyslog, logrotate, rsyslogd

on a Centos 8 server, I attached a bigger disk mounted to /mnt/data. The server runs rsyslogd which has a policy to write logs from external systems to /mnt/data/logs/$HOSTNAME.
I do now have the problem that either logrotate doesn't rotate the logs when selinux fcontext for /mnt/data/logs is set to "syslogd_var_lib_t" , or rsyslod doesn't write data to files when fcontext is set to "logrotate_var_lib_t".

I found several solutions for samba and httpd where bools are set to "*anon_write 1", but for syslog and logrotate, I don't see bools.

Is there a way to let selinux allow both logrotate and rsyslogd in /mnt/data/logs ?

sealert output with fcontext of /mnt/data/logs is set to 'logrotate_var_lib_t':

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/rsyslogd from append access on the file 10.9.7.15.log.                     

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that rsyslogd should be allowed append access on the 10.9.7.15.log file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'rs:main Q:Reg' --raw | audit2allow -M my-rsmainQReg
# semodule -X 300 -i my-rsmainQReg.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:object_r:logrotate_var_lib_t:s0
Target Objects                10.9.7.15.log [ file ]
Source                        rs:main Q:Reg
Source Path                   /usr/sbin/rsyslogd
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          HAMS010125.global.bdfgroup.net
Source RPM Packages           rsyslog-8.1911.0-6.el8.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
SELinux Policy RPM            selinux-policy-targeted-3.14.3-54.el8.noarch
Local Policy RPM              selinux-policy-targeted-3.14.3-54.el8.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     HAMS010125.global.bdfgroup.net
Platform                      Linux HAMS010125.global.bdfgroup.net
                              4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19
                              17:20:08 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   68679
First Seen                    2021-03-30 07:47:58 CEST
Last Seen                     2021-03-30 10:47:03 CEST
Local ID                      5ee9e182-0188-4ac8-b28e-5c8c9ab18933

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1617094023.794:76568): avc:  denied  { append } for  pid=1452 comm=72733A6D61696E20513A526567 n
ame="10.9.7.15.log" dev="dm-3" ino=23330820 scontext=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:log
rotate_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1617094023.794:76568): arch=x86_64 syscall=openat success=no exit=EACCES a0=ffffff9c a1=7f8
2b40a4fa0 a2=80541 a3=1a4 items=0 ppid=1 pid=1452 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0
fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=rs:main Q:Reg exe=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd subj=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 ke
y=(null)

Hash: rs:main Q:Reg,syslogd_t,logrotate_var_lib_t,file,append
```

sealert output with fcontext of /mnt/data/logs set to 'syslogd_var_lib_t':

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/logrotate from read access on the file 10.9.7.16.log.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that logrotate should be allowed read access on the 10.9.7.16.log file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'logrotate' --raw | audit2allow -M my-logrotate
# semodule -X 300 -i my-logrotate.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:logrotate_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
Target Context                system_u:object_r:syslogd_var_lib_t:s0
Target Objects                10.9.7.16.log [ file ]
Source                        logrotate
Source Path                   /usr/sbin/logrotate
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          HAMS010125.global.bdfgroup.net
Source RPM Packages
Target RPM Packages
SELinux Policy RPM            selinux-policy-targeted-3.14.3-54.el8.noarch
Local Policy RPM              selinux-policy-targeted-3.14.3-54.el8.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     HAMS010125.global.bdfgroup.net
Platform                      Linux HAMS010125.global.bdfgroup.net
                              4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19
                              17:20:08 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   8
 First Seen                    2021-03-26 02:51:01 CET
 Last Seen                     2021-03-29 02:51:01 CEST
 Local ID                      9ee8b323-1833-484b-b7c7-4b746c30d60b

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1616979061.951:6206): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=632546 comm="logrotate" name="10.9.7.16.$
og" dev="dm-3" ino=23330825 scontext=system_u:system_r:logrotate_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:sysl$
gd_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

 
Hash: logrotate,logrotate_t,syslogd_var_lib_t,file,read
```

Any hint appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you see the remark "You can generate a local policy module to allow this access" in the `sealert` output?

Comment: Yes, of course. I tried to generate local policies, but when one alert was gone, the next came up. I came to the point to think about, if this would be the right way to build several policies or if it would be better to check labeling.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark your log directory with the same label as the `/var/log` has. Then call restorecon on it to take effect.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t var_log_t /mnt/data/logs
restorecon /mnt/data/logs
```

It will work as long as the actual files under `/mnt/data/logs` are created by rsyslog and rotated with logrotate. You may have to mark your `$HOSTNAME` directories; depending on your setup.

A bit more correct way is to create your own selinux policy which allows operations you need. This can be done automatically with relevant `audit.log` lines and `audit2allow` tool.

Other possibility is to just set selinux to permissive for logrotate with `semanage permissive -a logrotate_t`. And the same way for rsyslog. **But** this effectively removes system-wide protection for logrotate and rsyslog should one of them went nuts, so I do not recommend it.

Comment: I just set `semanage fcontext -m -e /var/log '/mnt/data/logs(/.*)?' ` and `restorecon -vvR /mnt/data/logs` and will wait for crontab initiated logrotate tomorrow.

To be honest, I would prefer to avoid setting daemons to 'permissive'. My position is to configure things the right way and not to deactivate well developed security mechanisms.